# Problem with validating header/data fields from JQuery AJAX to Backend flask API

Tags: python-3.x, ajax, flask

I'm trying to pass JWT token and data fields via Jquery and then consume those values in Flask.

So, my client side query looks like this:

```
    function getData() {
            var data = {
                    UserPoolId : 'AWS CognitoUser Pool Id',
                    ClientId : 'AWS CognitoUser client Id'
                };
            var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(data);
            var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
            
         cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
                    if (err) {
                        alert(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log('session validity: ' + session.isValid());
                    console.log(cognitoUser.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken);

                    //
                    $.ajax({
                              url: "/api/v1/count",
                              type: "POST",
                              headers: { "X-Test-Header": cognitoUser.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken },
                              // data: JSON.stringify(data),
                              data: JSON.stringify("{'UserPoolId': 'XXXX','ClientId': 'XXXX'}"),
                              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                              error: function(err) {
                                switch (err.status) {
                                  case "400":
                                    // bad request
                                    break;
                                  case "401":
                                    // unauthorized
                                    break;
                                  case "403":
                                    // forbidden
                                    break;
                                  default:
                                    //Something bad happened
                                    break;
                                }
                              },
                              success: function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                              }
                     });
                    //
                });
}
```

Now, in my serverside flask:
I tried to catch the token value using below: which is not working

```
@app.route("/api/v1/count", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_data_count():
    if 'X-Test-Header' in request.headers:
            headers = request.headers
            app.logger.info(headers)
            auth = headers.get("X-Test-Header")
            app.logger.info('testing info log' + auth)
```

Also I tried to catch the data fields , using `result = request.get_json()` also not working.
I tried to inspect in chrome, and I don't see these values being added to the request header.

[image: inspect]

Can anyone suggest to me if I'm doing it correctly while passing the values from client to server? I also don't see `console.log(cognitoUser.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken)` in the console log.

if not can anyone suggest to me, how to fix it?

Comment: You are setting the headers for your request correctly, did you check your browser's JavaScript console for any errors? It looks like you're missing a comma at end of the `data` line and why do you have `data: data:` there twice?

Comment: @vremes sorry for missing comma and 2 times data, those were a silly copy-paste error, It's actually one data.

Comment: I tested your JS code with Flask and both `request.headers.get('X-Test-Header')` and `request.get_json()` are working fine on my end, tested with jQuery 3.5.1 and Flask 1.1.2

Comment: However, it's noteworthy to mention that i stripped down some parts of your JS code to make it work on my end since everything related to `cognitoUser` is undefined on my end of course, here is the version that worked for me https://pastebin.com/PzEG9zhT